# ng prerender hangs but doesn't show error

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to implement prerendering for my Angular app in order to improve SEO.
I use `"routes": ["/", "/my-sub-path"], "guessRoutes": false` in `angular.json`.
Running `ng run my-app-name:prerender` compiles and then keeps hanging at

```
Prerendering 2 route(s) to /home/my-user-name/my-path
```

Is there a way to see where it's hanging or what's the problem?

I tried activating `guessRoutes`, but that didn't help either. I also added `pathMatch: 'full'` where it was missing in the routing modules.